# "orphanRemoval = true" is not deleting child object when delete operation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

Below two classes(CD & DVD) are not related to each other.Each have different table.But both have subclass like Address.

While saving values of DVD/CD,the entry is inserting in respective table.So when I am trying to add values in Address_Table,it is inserting properly with primary key of CD & DVD.

When I'm trying to delete the entry in Address_Table,it is not deleting
I think by using "orphanRemoval = true" is not working.

For this scenerio,any related annotation to be use?Because while using xml file it is working fine.

//DVD class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="DVD_Table")
public class DVDPO{

    //some code

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,targetEntity=com.AddressPO.class,cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @MapKeyColumn(name="LOG_GUID")
    @JoinColumn(name = "FK_GUID")
    private Map<String, PersistentObject> auditEntry = new HashMap<String, PersistentObject>();

}
```

//CD class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CD_Table")
public class CDPO{

    //some code

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,targetEntity=com.AddressPO.class,cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @MapKeyColumn(name="LOG_GUID")
    @JoinColumn(name = "FK_GUID")
    private Map<String, PersistentObject> auditEntry = new HashMap<String, PersistentObject>();

}
```

//Address class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Address_Table")
public class AddressPO{

    @Any(metaColumn = @Column(name = "CLASS_NAME"), fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @AnyMetaDef(idType = "java.lang.String", metaType = "string", metaValues = {
            @MetaValue( targetEntity = com.DVDPO.class, value = "DVD"),
            @MetaValue(targetEntity = com.CDPO.class, value = "CD"),    

   @JoinColumn(name="FK_GUID")
   private PersistentObject persistentObject;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete the `AddressPO` you have to disassociate it from the DVDPO and CDPO object that are associated to the current `Session`.

```
PersistentObject po = ...;
DVDPO dvdpo = ...;
CDPO cdpo = ...;
dvdpo.getAuditEntry().values().remove(po);
cdpo.getAuditEntry().values().remove(po);
```